# Ruby on Rails Tutorial, Chapter 11, Exercise 7 - Breaks my rspec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, nested-routes

I'm working through Michael Hartl's excellent tutorial on Rails, but I am having trouble with exercise 7 in Chapter 11.

This exercise is:

> Add a nested route so that
>   /users/1/microposts shows all the
>   microposts for user 1. (You will also
>   have to add a Microposts controller
>   index action and corresponding view.)

I've done this successfully by changing my `routes.rb` file to read:

```
resources :users do
  resources :microposts, :only => [:create, :destroy]
end
```

I am able to successfully call /users/1/microposts from a browser.  However, most of the tests in microposts_controller_spec.rb are now broken.  I receive the "no route matches" error when running autotest.  For instance, the first test, which simply reads:

```
it "should deny access to 'create'" do
  post :create
  response.should redirect_to(signin_path)
end
```

now produces the following error:

> 1) MicropostsController access
>   control should deny access to 'create'
>        Failure/Error: post :create
>        No route matches {:controller=>"microposts",
>   :action=>"create"}

When I check `rake routes`

, I find this entry:

```
user_microposts POST   /users/:user_id/microposts(.:format)     {:action=>"create", :controller=>"microposts"}
```

which suggests the route does exist.

Has anyone else run into this issue while completing the tutorial?  Is there a change I need to make in the spec file once I introduce nested routes?  Does Rspec work with nested routes?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this is a nested route you will need to pass the `user_id` through:

```
some_user = way_of_creating_a_user_goes_here
post :create, :user_id => some_user.id
```

RSpec will attempt to go to the `/microposts` route without this parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ryan.  I thought I tried this but evidently I didn't do it quite correctly - your solution works so far.